# C# WindowsForm error at Resume/Perform layout

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

My program has 3 different form. In the SecondMenu.Designer.cs i got an error at
`this.PerformLayout();` or `this.ResumeLayout(false);`[image]

my secondmenu code is:

```
private void SecondMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1;
checkBox2.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox2;
checkBox3.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox3;
checkBox4.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox4;
textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox1;
textBox2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox2;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           this.Hide();
           FirstMenu fomenu = new FirstMenu();
           Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1 = checkBox1.Checked;
           Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox2 = checkBox2.Checked;
           Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox3 = checkBox3.Checked;
           Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox4 = checkBox4.Checked;
           Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox1 = textBox1.Text;
           Properties.Settings.Default.TextBox2 = textBox2.Text;
           Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
           fomenu.Show();
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal & your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env & data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of screens, & user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: the problem is i'm not familiar with this codes and i dont how how can i resolve this, after i start the program my cpu & ram usage go high and the visual studio open the secodmenu.designer.cs file and show the problem, the funny thing is that i dont even touched the secondmenu codes or design, before i started coding today (10min) the program was still able to run, after i detected the crash i deleted my progress (just a few line of code) but the program was still had errors

Comment: Did you add code in the constructor and had you added handlers on some valuechanged or selecteditemchanged or textchanged and so on events on textbox, combobox, listbox and so on ?

Comment: no, i used the textbox for user input and button to do something (basically my program write some numbers (e.g:5+5) and check and write the correct value)

Comment: Can you put the project folder in a zip on a downloadable online place ? It will be quicker.

Comment: https://mega.nz/file/mUxDSJKA#7Pf4pID_vIONsuGZQzbAaqllRsy6rEizeVqFcitmb_4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From the .rar provided

There is in **FirstMenu.cs** this field initialization:

```
GameMenu fojatek = new GameMenu();
```

And in **GameMenu.cs**:

```
FirstMenu fomenu = new FirstMenu();
```

So the *stack overflow exception*.

You should rethink your design to solve that.

You can for example:

- Set all the concerned forms as *singleton* with private constructors,
- Or instantiate them in the `Main` method by adding these fields in the `Program` class.

You may check the same thing for others forms.